# assign input to variable if input is condition of while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if it is possible in Python to assign the value from an input statement to a variable, while making the presence of input the condition of a while loop.

What I tried:

```
while w = input("Enter word to define:\n").lower():
    output = define_word(w)
    if type(output) = list:
        for item in output:
            print(item)
```

What I got:

```
File "main.py", line 23
while w = input("Enter word to define:\n").lower():
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am curious if there is a way of assigning user input to a variable provided there is any user input instead of repeating the same input statement within the loop and assigning it to a variable separately.
Thank you, criticism is welcome, this is my first question on Stackoverflow ever...

Comment: No, wait for [Python 3.8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).